# Issues with language bundles: the columns names are missing

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports

I have a report where in I am trying to test localization

So, I have 3 language files present in a folder which has been configured as source path

Now, the table in the report has four columns. country, state, name and age. 3 language files are present language_en_US, langauage_fr_FR, language_pt_PT.The names for each of these columns are present in each file according to the respective language. I have configured the text expressions of the columns headers of the table with `$R{}`

1. But all column headers have the name as null when I run the report. Why is this happening?
2. How do I pick different languages in run time? The report always runs for en_US which is the default? I do want to use the report_locale parameter
3. Can I use another parameter, set its value to a desired locale and then pass this locale to the bundle?

Please find below the jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testinterntionalization" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" resourceBundle="languages/languages" uuid="c3bdcfb8-c39a-4ce6-b38c-e7f05aa12d1b">
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="1d6f72b2-0f11-41ac-b81e-e83ff3318002">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="mysqldev"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select * from testinternationalization;]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="country" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="state" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="age" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="locale" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <summary>
        <band height="270" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="411" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="d832c916-8101-4bc1-bc94-2ac5519c0456"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{locale}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="10" y="70" width="510" height="100" uuid="808bf878-b921-4858-b9d4-4dee5c866c89"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="92016b66-2c36-46c9-b417-ed67c60ebb5c">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="6a314d61-4759-4396-9796-bc890f4018d0">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="700b5c4a-53ee-4c25-9202-a7cf5960b8f1">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{country}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="96d38f9c-1461-4cf6-b43d-5ddc7b031a19">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="07dbe77e-5f72-44b8-981c-62f4dd5a7fcd">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{state}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="c26b379e-d8aa-4ede-a79c-b4e521f2bd00">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="7d71e238-237a-4ff3-83f4-8768995cab50">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="4581f4df-2aa4-474f-925c-c2d7e4cb7795">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="50be640f-e779-4ba7-95c7-a92377628278">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="40" width="100" height="30" uuid="5b5f292d-2a86-4dfb-a30b-bd3c71d22d79"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{languages.country}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="40" width="100" height="30" uuid="fdf7454f-068e-4e6f-8f40-e3a0ab8d9fe6"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{languages.state}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="210" y="40" width="100" height="30" uuid="96b616fd-219d-4a74-8a6e-c2143bd45ae3"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{languages.name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="310" y="40" width="100" height="30" uuid="38acca04-4b84-4975-b74b-ad930f867e21"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{languages.age}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Any help on this?

Comment: You should post: 1) the code for testing this template; 2) the folder structure with resources (where is the properties file is located and what is its name)

Comment: Hi Alex, I haven't written any extra code other than this jrxml. Apologies as I am quite new to this feature. the properties file is located in under MyReport/language folder which contains the 3 files langauges_en_US.properties, langauges_fr_FR.properties and langauges_pt_PT.properties.

Comment: You have `resourceBundle="languages/languages"` - it means that JR engine is looking for `languages_*.properties` file(s) at `languages` folder

Comment: Hi Alex, I do have all the languages_*.properties under languages folder. But I do not understand why its taking the resourceBundle as "languages/languages"

Comment: I guess you are getting null since you did not add any query to your main datasource.

Comment: I have added a query to my main datasource and I get Document Empty report. My question is am I configuring the bundles correctly?

Comment: I could solve the document empty error. But like earlier the $R{} returns null.

Comment: I changes the properties files name to name testinterntionalization_*.properties and moved under the same folder the report resides in. I still don't get the translation. Its all null. Any ideas on this would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

I did figure this out. I had to make the $R{languages.country} to $R{country}. And change the resourceBundle="languages/languages"  to resourceBundle="languages"

Thanks 
Rathi